# Invalid expression term 'case' in switch statment

Tags: c#

I am getting a "Error 1 The name 'Switch' does not exist in the current context" and "Invalid expression term 'case'" errors in my switch statment. My question is what do these errors mean? Here is the switch

```
private void buttonRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Selected = listColours.SelectedIndex;
            Colours newColour;

            Switch(Selected)
            {
                case 0:
                newColour = Colours.red;
                MessageBox.Show(newColour.ToString(), "Output", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;

                case 1:
                newColour = Colours.orange;
                MessageBox.Show(newColour.ToString(), "Output", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;

                case 2:
                newColour = Colours.yellow;
                MessageBox.Show(newColour.ToString(), "Output", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;

                case 3:
                newColour = Colours.green;
                MessageBox.Show(newColour.ToString(), "Output", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;

                case 4:
                newColour = Colours.blue;
                MessageBox.Show(newColour.ToString(), "Output", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;

                case 5:
                newColour = Colours.purple;
                MessageBox.Show(newColour.ToString(), "Output", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;
            }
```

Comment: have you try to make `Switch` keyword to lowercase?

Comment: It should be `switch`, not `Switch` (note the case)

Comment: ah thankyou, the little syntax errors can go right past you. cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`C#` is case-sensitive, so you have to type the keywords exactly, change `Switch` to `switch` and it should work.